# App-Wide Styling Using VisualStates in UWP (since Style Triggers Aren't Supported)

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm new to UWP and have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out something that was very easy in WPF. Basically, I want the equivalent of Style Triggers to allow me to define control appearances in different states. What I desire:

- I want all TextBoxes in the app to have an AliceBlue BorderBrush when they are focused.

All TextBoxes. Across the entire app. In WPF, I could define this in my `App.xaml` using a Style with Triggers targeting all TextBoxes. It was easy. But I'm struggling to do the same using VisualStates. All examples I see define VisualStates per `Page`, not at the app level. The only way I've found to do this is to copy the entire [UWP TextBox style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) into my app and change the properties I want in the "Focused" state.

Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: IMHO changing the *Focused* state is the best way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting Windows 10, version 1607 (Build 14393) and above, there are some resource values that you can change for this (the full list is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox#remarks)).

If you override this in your Application.Resources as below:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushFocused" Color="Fuchsia" />
```

It should take affect everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> I want all TextBoxes in the app to have an AliceBlue BorderBrush when they are focused.

For you scenario you could also create the textbox [`style`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) in `Application.Resources`, which is located in `App.xaml` file. One thing you need to pay attention to is that you could't set `x:Key="XXXXStyle"` for style. And it will modify the default system styles. The following is sample code.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style  TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}">
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}" FontStyle="Normal" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE10A;" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,8" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                            <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" />
                            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}" MinWidth="34" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

If you want want all TextBoxes in the app to have an AliceBlue BorderBrush when they are focused you just set the `BorderBrush` of `BorderElement` as your desired color.

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
```

**Usage**

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Width="100" Height="44" />
```

**Effect**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for an answer that fulfills my requirements. However, I was already aware of this option and was hoping that there would be a way of changing these properties on element focus *without* having to copy the entire `TextBox` style into my `App.xaml`. I would prefer to be able to just override the few properties I need (as I used to do with Triggers) while leaving the rest to the system.

Comment: @NSouth The Darshan's answer  is perfect. Starting in Windows 10, version 1607 (Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) version 10.0.14393.0), generic.xaml includes resources that you can use to modify the colors of a control in different visual states without modifying the control template. In apps that target this software development kit (SDK) or later, modifying these resources is preferred to setting properties such as Background and Foreground. For more info, see the  Light-weight styling section of the Styling controls article.